# How many ways to vote?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

> A ballot contains  a list of $5$ candidates. Each voter can choose $0$ to $5$ candidates. In how many ways can a voter complete the ballot?
>
> 1. $17$
> 2. $20$
> 3. $32$
> 4. $125$

I tried doing $5!$ and I get $120$...

Comment: Remember, there is no ordering here : a voter simply "chooses" a subset of  the voters, without ordering them in any way. Then every such voter is basically picking a subset of the list of candidates, but not ordering them further or anything.

Comment: ... because you have counted the $120$ different ways to express the same vote. @donna

Comment: Please, don't use an image if it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: If this were a preferential ballot, you would have to remember not all $5$ choices need to be taken, so the answer would be $\frac{5!}{5!}+\frac{5!}{4!}+\frac{5!}{3!}+\frac{5!}{2!}+\frac{5!}{1!}+\frac{5!}{0!} =\lfloor 120e\rfloor=326$

Comment: Why have you tried “doing $5!$”? What would that count and what do you need to count? In your case, the voter decides whether to choose or not to choose each of the 5 candidates, and these choices are independent. You would need the factorial if you were choosing how to order all of them, but that’s not what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

If choices are not ordered as @Aston suggests, then
any of the five candidates can be either chosen or not: $2^5 = 32.$
Also, $\sum_{i=0}^5 {5 \choose i} = 32.$

Note: By the binomial theorem, $(x + y)^5 = \sum_{i=0}^5 {5 \choose i}x^iy^{5-i}.$
Take $x = y = 1$ to show that the two methods count the same outcomes.